# align button text and other ion-col text to bottom in ionic 2

Tags: css, ionic2

my code looks like:

```
<ion-row><ion-col ><button ion-button outline no-padding  large (click)="setUserName()">D</button>ay in the life </ion-col></ion-row>
```

this looks ugly as the letter D goes in the middle and overall col text a bit above.

all i want is everything bottom aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happen?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ion-row class='row'>
  <ion-col class='col'><button ion-button outline no-padding large (click)="setUserName()">D</button>ay in the life </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: looks like it will do. though sounds a lot of css for this simple requirement

Comment: This is basic css what ionic self define in framework

Comment: didnt get u. if ionic defines then why i have to define again?

Comment: I mean if you dont have any other css, it will look like this. There are some css what you added make your button ugly and you need to find it out.